# Rails serving .otf file with wrong MIME type. application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, font-face, mime-types, ruby-on-rails-4

Here's what I've done:

First I created a `fonts` folder inside the `app/assets` directory.

---

Then I configured the asset pipeling to recognize this new folder.

`config/environments/development.rb`:

```
# Add the fonts path
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')

# Precompile additional assets
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf .otf )
```

---

Next, I configure the mime type in `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Here are some example that came with the default Rails project.

# Add new mime types for use in respond_to blocks:
# Mime::Type.register "text/richtext", :rtf
# Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :iphone

Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES['.otf'] = 'application/x-font-opentype'
```

---

Finally, I reference the font in my SCSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ArnoProDisplay';
  src: url('ArnoPro-Display.otf');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I'm using Google Chrome and the console says:

```
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template: 
"http://localhost:3000/assets/ArnoPro-Display.otf".
```

I can see the font correctly in the Network tab:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update

**Solution 1**

Change `application/x-font-opentype` to `font/opentype` . Source : [font mime type](http://www.jbarker.com/blog/2011/resource-interpreted-font-transferred-mime-type)

`Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES['.otf'] = 'font/opentype'`

and wipe out the cache

```
rake tmp:cache:clear
```

before restarting the server.

---

If **solution 1** not works,  you should create file `.htaccess` and add this

`AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template .otf`

Comment: Changed it, restarted my server and having the same issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: Updated answer, if not works, you can create `.htaccess` file and add `AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template      .otf`

Comment: Wouldn't your edit set the MIME type **to** `vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template`? I'm trying to prevent it from having that mime type, not encourage it.

Comment: Your third update (Adding `src: url(/assets/ArnoPro-Display.otf);`) doesn't work because the actual url for the font becomes `assets/assets/ArnoPro-Display.otf`. Remember, I registered the folder in the asset pipeline.

Comment: @Serg : sorry Serg, I have clean and updated my answer. After change `mime_type.rb` you should `wipe out the cache` before restart. Hope this help.

Comment: The solution was the set the MIME type as you said above, and also **to clear the cache using Rake.**